# Keyboard suddenly stops working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, suspend, hp, reboot

I have have this weird keyboard issue on my HP Envy 17 laptop on which I am running Ubuntu 22.04. The keyboard usually works fine, but sometimes (around once or twice a day) it just stops working, as if out of nowhere. I can be typing something and it suddenly just stops working or I can try to get into my computer after it was suspended and I won't be able to type in the password. Sometimes, the issue resolves itself after I suspend and try to open the computer a few times, sometimes I need to restart it with the power button, after which the keyboard starts working again.

I would really appreciate some help on this. Thanks!

Comment: [this](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/New-HP-Envy-keyboard-randomly-stops-working/td-p/8861286) may be of interest to you